# Using sort and function object , but the function object cannot modify member variables

Tags: c++, sorting

I wrote the code like the below, I don't know why the member variable flag did't equal 1 after sort process? Can someone give me suggestion.

Code:

```
class Func{
public:
    int flag;
    Func()
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
    bool operator()(int &l, int &r)
    {
        if(l==r)
        {
            flag = 1;   
        }
        return l > r;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<int> a;
    int b[] = {11,8,7,6,4,3,4,1};
    for(int i = 0; i <sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]); i++)
    {
        a.push_back(b[i]);
    }

    Func FuncObj = Func();
    std::sort(begin(a), end(a), FuncObj);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say `flag` was not `1` after sorting, but your code never reads `flag` at all.  Post your actual code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Flag equals to 1 only if r and l are equals, but this might not happen during sorting, even the fact that you have two 4 in the data set.

Comment: Off topic: Rather than `    std::vector<int> a;
    int b[] = {11,8,7,6,4,3,4,1};` and a `for` loop to copy, assign directly to the vector: `std::vector<int> a = {11,8,7,6,4,3,4,1};`

Comment: On topic: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: i add a break in the flag = 1, it has run to it, i'm use cout << FuncObj.flag << endl， finally it print 0

Comment: Because `FuncObj` is passed by value. `std::sort` operates on a copy of `FuncObj`, `flag` is set to ` in the copy of `FuncObj` and `FuncObj` is unchanged.

Comment: By the way, good on you for using the debugger. Now inspect the address of `FuncObj` and compare it to `this` inside `operator()`. You will see that they are different objects.

Comment: FuncObj pass by value in sort sounds reasonable, but  how to let it don't pass by value?

Comment: @user6927970 You can't, because that would entail changing the signature of `std::sort`, which you can't do. Try marking `flag` as `static` so that it is the same no matter which instance you have.

Comment: using static member variables can work,thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to reliable documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), `std::sort` accepts the function object by value. This means the `Func` being used by `std::sort` is a copy of  `FuncObj`. This means that when 4 is compared with 4, the copy's `flag` variable is set to 1, and `FuncObj` is unchanged. The copy is destroyed when `std::sort` returns, so this `flag` is lost.

The simplest solution define `int flag` as `static int flag` to that all instances of `Func` share the same `Flag`.

If this is not an option, different `Func`s must have their own `flag`, my inclination was to go with a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Each default constructed `Func` would have had it's own `flag` and shared this `flag` with any copies made.

However Benjamin Lindley reminds of [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and this provides a much more convenient solution for the problem. The wrapper is passed by value and copied rather then the `Func` it references, allowing the source `Func` to be modified inside `std::sort`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class Func{
public:
    int flag;
    Func(): flag(0)
    {
    }
    bool operator()(int &l, int &r)
    {
        if(l==r)
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        return l > r;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {11,8,7,6,4,3,4,1};

    Func FuncObj = Func();
    std::sort(begin(a), end(a), std::reference_wrapper<Func>(FuncObj));
    std::cout << FuncObj.flag;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The most straightforward, and idiomatic way to solve this is with a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). This is precisely the purpose for which it exists.

Comment: Can argue with that, but I'd be stupid to. You have raisins, @BenjaminLindley . One more edit coming up.